# Excel option to calculate values for each cell only once

Tags: vba, excel

I have a project whose requirements include a circular reference (just so you know why I'm deliberately putting this in my workbook).

Within the doc, I'd like for each cell in the circle to calculate only once. I know this is possible through the Windows Button > Excel Options > Formulas > Enable Iterative Calculations, but I have no way to enforce that option on everyone who touches the workbook. Is there any way (through VBA, maybe, or cell/sheet options?) to make a cell calculate its value only once?

Sounds like a longshot to me, but I really really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You should try turning Calculation to Manual but do not check Recalculate Before Saving, then enabling Iterative Calculation setting the number to 1 and Maximum Change to Zero.

Comment: @chuff Setting the calculations to manual won't work because the cells are script-fed - so they DO need to be calculated automatically, but then only once. Thank you, though!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: under which circumstances do you need a circular reference - and then only calculate it for one iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Application
    .Iteration = True
    .MaxIterations = 1 '<-- or whatever the maximum allowable # you want
    .MaxChange = 0.001  '<-- modify as necessary, or remove if desired
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Close()
    Application.Iteration = False
End Sub
```

Place these in the Workbook module.

This was one of the first answers on Google, which you would've found had you done any searching on your own:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/444155-need-macro-enable-iterative-calculation.html

Comment: I did do searching on my own, and that's really rude of you to make anonymous accusations. Out of curiosity, what did you search for to find that link? Obviously I wasn't explaining my question to Google very well :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Google search for "VBA enable iterative calculation Excel", this was the second result. :)  The third result also has some important information about this being an Application-level setting (i.e., setting this on one file WILL impact other open workbooks). In order to avoid similar reprimands in the future, it is preferable to demonstrate some effort rather than simply posing open-ended questions.

Comment: I appreciate the additional help - no excuse except a brain fart for not Googling that! I also read a conversation on here about making posts short and sweet, so that has always affected how I ask questions. I *did* put effort into the research for this question, I just didn't *demonstrate* that effort. Again, thank you.